# Cascading Ruby Logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to do the following for a **signed out** user without triggering a `.consumer` being called on nil error?

```
if signed_in? && current_user.consumer
  puts "Hello world"
end
```

For most of my site I have had to nest these types of conditionals like:

```
if signed_in?
  if current_user.consumer
  end
end
```

...which doesn't look that bad, but when you have lots of other code on the page, it can be a hassle..

I want statement where `signed_in?`
 is evaluated and if true the second conditional is evaluated... but all in a single line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Ruby supports short-circuiting logic, so your first code block will do exactly what you want: if `signed_in?` evaluates to `false`, the Ruby interpreter will be lazy and will not bother evaluating the rest of the condition.

Similarly, if the user were not signed in, `!signed_in? || current_user.banned?` would short-circuit when it realizes that `!signed_in?` is `true` and not bother to evaluate `current_user.banned?`.